# R data.table split into list of data.tables by multiple named columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have this `dt` and I would like to split it into a list of data.tables by the contents of each column.

```
'%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')
dt <- setDT(copy(diamonds))
split_by <- paste0("dt$",colnames(dt)[colnames(dt) %ni% c("x","y")])
dt_to_list <- split(dt, list(dt$carat, dt$cut)) #works
dt_to_list <- split(dt, list(split_by)) # does not work
```

I would like to minimize overhead and memory use, so if there is a better approach to achieve what I am after, I'm more than happy to revise.

Comment: Don't use `$` in these cases....

Comment: Do you mean I should use [[?

Comment: `[[` won't work with multiple columns.

Comment: The example I provide is adequate to demonstrate what is needed. Yes, I plan to split by all but `"x"` and `"y"`. I realize it might be bad practice, but I don't have an alternative...

Comment: Also, since you're using "data.table", have you considered something like `dt[, list(list(.SD)), by = split_by]`? The resulting "V1" will be your `list` of `data.table`s. Not exactly what you wanted....

Comment: I suppose you could do: `dt[, list(list(.SD)), by = split_by, .SDcols = names(dt)]`.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for converting a data.table `dt` of 53940 rows into a list of 53621 elements, where 53313 of the elements consist of just one row. See `dt[, .N, by = split_by][order(-N)][, .N, by = N]`.

Comment: @Uwe thank you. I agree the reason is not evident from the example. This is just for demonstrative purposes and reproducibility. In my case, I would have a unique time series for each. The actual dataset is already in long format and cannot be simplified further.

Comment: So, why can't you further process your timeseries group-wise with the data.table using `by =`?. The `j` expression in a data.table is very powerful and can be used even to create plots for each group.